# R - error on factor trying edit strings in vector

Tags: r, indexing

I have a simple misunderstanding of the basic syntax in R.

I have a vector `title` of length 145. I try to set all values above the threshold `top`(=50) to `" "`. 
However, when I put

```
title[(top+1):length(data.[,1])]
```

I get an error

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, (top + 1):length(data[, 1]), value = " ") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

How should I do it right?

**EDIT:**

The workaround I used is:
`title <- c(title[1:top],replicate(length(title)-top,""))`

data example:

```
title <- unlist(data[,1])

> head(title)

[1] Shanghai  Yantian   Busan     Ningbo    Hong Kong Kaohsiung
262 Levels: Aarhus Abidjan Acajutla Adelaide Agadir Ahus Algeciras Anguilla Antofagasta Antwerp Apia Apra (Agana) Aqaba (El Akaba) Arica ... Zeebrugge

> length(data[,1])

[1] 145
```

Comment: You have a factor column as the error says.  Also, use parentheses around `(1:length`

Comment: It does not matter. Even if I write `title[top+1:length(data[,1])-top]`, I get the same error

Comment: Then, consider to show some reproducible example for others to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get the same error with

```
x <- factor(letters[1:3]); 
x[3] <- " "
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 3, value = " ") :
#   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

You get a warning (not an error) that you are attempting to add a new level to a factor. When you create a factor, R assumes that you've specified all the levels (in this case `x` expects only values of "a", "b", or "c". If you wanted to allow for other values, you could specify them in the `levels=` parameter.

```
x <- factor(letters[1:3], levels=c(letters[1:3]," "))
x[3] <- " "
# no error
```

Comment: Wow, why is it so complicated? I'm a little surprised. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`a+b:c` is `a + (b:c)` not `(a + b):c`. See `?Syntax` for the precedence of operators.

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve the final question on the reason for the warning and NA instead of " "